# Animate bar visible only on circle - svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg

How to make this animated green bar visible only on circle?

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 x="0px" y="0px" width="38px" height="38px" viewBox="0 0 38 38" xml:space="preserve">
<rect id="bar" y="10.962" fill="#02FF74" width="38" height="14.667">
```

[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybabXj)

Comment: Only on which part of the circle? One of the black circles? All of the black circles? One of the white circles, All of the white circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a clipPath you can create a mask.

1. you have a to create a `<circle>` inside a `<defs>` tag( it doesn't render element inside it and make it accessible )
2. you have to create a `clipPath` thate takes sizes and position from the circle using `<use xlink:href="#circleID"...`
3. you should add the attribute `clipPath="url(#clipPathID)"` to any element or group of element you want to mask.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 38 38" enable-background="new 0 0 37.833 37.833" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <defs>
  <circle id="SVGID_1_" cx="19" cy="19" r="19"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
  <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
 </clipPath>
 <rect id="bar" y="10.962" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#02FF74" width="38" height="14.667">
 
  <animate  fill="freeze" from="40" to="-15" restart="always" dur="2s" attributeName="y" calcMode="linear" additive="replace" accumulate="none" repeatCount="indefinite">
  </animate>
 </rect>
 <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
  <path d="M19,4.191c8.166,0,14.809,6.643,14.809,14.809S27.166,33.809,19,33.809S4.191,27.165,4.191,19S10.834,4.191,19,4.191
    M19,0C8.508,0,0,8.507,0,19s8.508,19,19,19c10.493,0,19-8.507,19-19S29.493,0,19,0L19,0z"/>
       <g>
   <path d="M19,13.691c2.928,0,5.309,2.381,5.309,5.309S21.928,24.309,19,24.309S13.691,21.927,13.691,19S16.072,13.691,19,13.691
     M19,9.5c-5.246,0-9.5,4.253-9.5,9.5s4.254,9.5,9.5,9.5s9.5-4.253,9.5-9.5S24.246,9.5,19,9.5L19,9.5z"/
       </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Just edited to show the animated element just inside the black fill of your circles. The process is the same of the previous example, but now The shape of the mask path has been created copying the `d=".."` attribute value from both black circles:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 38 38" enable-background="new 0 0 37.833 37.833" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
   <g>
    <path d="M19,4.191c8.167,0,14.809,6.643,14.809,14.809c0,8.167-6.643,14.809-14.809,14.809c-8.166,0-14.809-6.645-14.809-14.809
   C4.191,10.835,10.834,4.191,19,4.191 M19,0C8.508,0,0,8.507,0,19c0,10.493,8.508,19,19,19c10.493,0,19-8.508,19-19
   C38,8.507,29.493,0,19,0L19,0z"/>
      <g>
    <path d="M19,13.691c2.928,0,5.309,2.381,5.309,5.309c0,2.928-2.381,5.309-5.309,5.309S13.691,21.926,13.691,19
    C13.691,16.073,16.072,13.691,19,13.691 M19,9.5c-5.246,0-9.5,4.253-9.5,9.5c0,5.247,4.254,9.5,9.5,9.5
    c5.247,0,9.5-4.254,9.5-9.5C28.5,13.753,24.247,9.5,19,9.5L19,9.5z"/>
   </g>
 </g>
 <g>
 <defs>
 <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M19,4.191c8.167,0,14.809,6.643,14.809,14.809c0,8.167-6.643,14.809-14.809,14.809
    c-8.166,0-14.809-6.645-14.809-14.809C4.191,10.835,10.834,4.191,19,4.191 M19,0C8.508,0,0,8.507,0,19c0,10.493,8.508,19,19,19
    c10.493,0,19-8.508,19-19C38,8.507,29.493,0,19,0L19,0z M19,13.691c2.928,0,5.309,2.381,5.309,5.309
    c0,2.928-2.381,5.309-5.309,5.309S13.691,21.926,13.691,19C13.691,16.073,16.072,13.691,19,13.691 M19,9.5
    c-5.246,0-9.5,4.253-9.5,9.5c0,5.247,4.254,9.5,9.5,9.5c5.247,0,9.5-4.254,9.5-9.5C28.5,13.753,24.247,9.5,19,9.5L19,9.5z"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
  <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
 </clipPath>
  <rect id="bar" y="10.962" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#02FF74" width="38" height="14.667">
   <animate  fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" accumulate="none" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" attributeName="y" dur="2s" restart="always" to="-15" from="40">
   </animate>
  </rect>
 </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I know how to make bar under or up on black circle, but the problem is how to make that bar visible only on two black circles (don't cover white space)

Comment: Just a suggestion, change your answer title in something like, **how to create a mask on svg**, or **how to create a mask on svg animation** as other people can easily find it and get help from this answer. Maybe add more info about the result you would like to have in the answer description, for example, **"how to show the animated rectangole just in the black fill"**

Comment: yeah, looks great! I've already implemented this. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: @Norbert ok, don't forget to set the answer as right.